# Using Nested Classes and Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, class, instance-variables

Good Morning!  I am trying to understand classes in Java.  My task is to create an Employee class, a Name class, and an Address class and use these to store information into an Array.  Obviously my code below is still a work-in-progress, but I don't understand how to use the Name class and Address class to put the values into the Array.

In particular, in my switch (case 1) I am tying to assign the input for each attribute into the array, but I don't understand how class instances really work.  I have tried reading online and in my textbook, but none of the explanations are really clicking with me.

This is my first exposure to Java classes, so any explanations that will help me apply these concepts in the future (and not just in this code) would be much appreciated. I am really trying to learn this, not just finish a HW assignment.  Thank you in advance for your time and thought!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Employee {

    String fName = " ";
    String lName = " ";
    String city = " ";
    String state = " ";

    public static void main( String [] args ) {

        int choice; //For Menu option
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        boolean looping = true; //Loop the menu
        while(looping == true) {
            System.out.println( "1. Add New Employee" );
            System.out.println( "0. Exit" );
            System.out.print( "Choice: " );
            choice = input.nextInt();

            switch(choice) {
                case 0: {
                    System.out.println( "Goodbye." );
                    looping = false;
                    break;
                }
                case 1: {
                    Employee [] employeeInfo = new Employee[9];
                    for(int i = 0; i < employeeInfo.length ; i++) {
                        Scanner info = new Scanner( System.in );

                        System.out.print( "Enter the Employee's First Name: ");
                        employeeInfo[i].fName = info.nextLine();
                        System.out.print( "Enter the Employee's Last Name: ");
                        employeeInfo[i].lName = info.nextLine();
                        System.out.print( "Enter the Employee's City: ");
                        employeeInfo[i].city = info.nextLine();
                        System.out.print( "Enter the Employee's State: ");
                        employeeInfo[i].state = info.nextLine();
                        break;
                }
                default:
                    System.out.println( "Invalid option." );
            }
        }
    }

    class Name {

        private String fName;
        private String lName;

        //Constructors
        Name() { //no parameters

            fName = " ";
            lName = " ";
        }

        Name(String fName, String lName) { //parameters

            this.fName = fName;
            this.lName = lName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString () {

            return "The employee's name is: " + fName + " " + lName;
        }
    }

    class Address {

        private String city;
        private String state;

        //Constructors
        Address() {

            this.city = " ";
            this.state = " ";
        }

        Address( String city, String state ) {

            this.city = city;
            this.state = state;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString (){

            return "The employee's residence is " + city + ", " + state;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/. Your three classes have no reason to be nested. If you don't understand classes and objects yet, making them nested will make things even more confusing. Put each class into its own file.

Comment: Your Name and Address class should probably be fields like: `Address address` and `Name name`. Before assigning your input to the instance of each Employee in your array you have to create the instance first like `employeeInfo[i] = new Employee()`.

Comment: Thank you, @JBNizet this looks like it has a lot of really great examples.  I am looking at this bicycle example under the classes link and things are starting to make a little more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Employee[] employeeInfo = new Employee[9];` creates an array that can hold 9 `Employee` objects, but each element is initially null. You will need to fill each with a new `Employee` object. Inside your `for` loop, do this at the top:

```
employeeInfo[i] = new Employee();
```

You also need to move the `break` out of the `for` loop, to the bottom of the `case`. Otherwise, your program will only input one person's data, not nine people's.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisJester-Young, that makes perfect sense!  Can you think of a reason why my menu would be "skipping" my lName variable?  It prints the message but then skips it and prints the option for city right away without letting me input an lName.

Comment: AAAAH weird, changing nextLine(); to next(); fixes that.